# ways to separate passages in pdf using gap?

Tags: pdf, pdfminer, pdftotext, pymupdf, pdfium

I have some pdf's with 2-3 passages for every page. every passage is separated by some line gap, but while reading with pymupdf, I cannot see any machine printable separator between passages. is there any other way, other library can do this?

code:

```
import fitz
from more_itertools import *
doc = fitz.open('IT_past.pdf',)
single_doc = doc.load_page(0)  # put here the page number
text=single_doc.get_text('text')
text
```

page screen shot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sDHQ.jpg)

pdf
[Full pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TefqSQhJpCx_sRjds3b9MqsDe4rpP4rF/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no gap as such, just for the moment as its much easier, lets look closer in your linked viewer rendering :-

[image]

So lets replicate what is inside the real PDF (that has no web side html `<p>` markers) :-

```
support, product design, HR Management, knowledge process outsourcing for
pharmaceutical companies and large complex projects.
Software exports make up 20 % of India's total export revenue in 2003-04, up from 4.9 %
in 1997.This figure is expected to go up to 44% of annual exports by 2010. Though India
```

See there is "no gap" just left aligned non justified (ragged) text that needs a style such as a font name and stretched out locations added to hold in a page de-void of line feeds nor true carriage returns. (occasionally there are some backspace or vertical/horizontal moves but generally meaningless in line printer text). Even "Tabs" "Indents" and some spatial characters are normally discarded in a PDF printout.

If you want gaps or line-wrap you need to add them.

A good alternative is export the `-layout` using poppler or xpdf ***here to - (console)*** or pipe it or replace that with a path/name.txt, many other options available like `-nopgbrk`

`xpdf-tools-win-4.04\bin32>pdftotext -f 1 -l 1 -layout IT_past.pdf -`

[image]